cannot input persian number in kendo react
i use kendo react numerictextbox but when paste persian number like ۲۷۱۵۰ not paste anything,can you help me how can fix it?
When I copy the number and paste it in the input, nothing is displayed and the value of the event is empty or the change is not executed at all.
use localization fa-ir

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
